# What is the objective c equivalent of UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape?

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the objc code for below swift statement?

```
if (UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape)
```

what i figured out so far is

```
  if  ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])
```

Comment: I think you can use this UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation) ,

Comment: @3stud1ant3 Thank you for reply . i checked on viewWillTransitionToSize it works when i rotate to landscape , i also added if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
        NSLog(@"Portrait");
    }
but it doesn't work

Comment: Please check when you rotate to portrait , your viewWillTransitionToSize method is being called or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From apple Docs:-

```
BOOL UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDeviceOrientation orientation);
```

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the device is in a
>   landscape orientation.

So try this:-

```
  if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)){
    //True if landscape is on
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. works on landscape but not in portrait please read last comment on Question

Comment: @ios have you enabled `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` like this `[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]` before checking these conditions?

Comment: Thank you for reply . works after restarting simulator. iam a newbie in iOS , do i have to place [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications] before condition?

Comment: See this apple [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620041-begingeneratingdeviceorientation?language=objc), it will clarify your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
BOOL isLandscape = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation);
if (isLandscape) {
    NSLog(@"Landscape orientation")
    //Do the work
}
```